# Ext JS 4's File Upload and Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, file-upload, extjs, error-handling, extjs4

Here we go again with Ext JS.

Suppose I have a file upload (Ext.form.field.File) field that submits an image to the app's Web Server.

Whenever I get an Internal Server Error (status code = 500) on the form's submission (ie: the posted file is bigger than the Web Server's max request length) Ext throws an Exception that show's on the browser's Console.

I can promptly catch the error if I override Ext.Error.handle like this:

```
<!-- language: js -->
Ext.Error.handle = function (err) {

    switch (err.sourceClass) {
        case "Ext.JSON":
            {
                var arr = err.msg.split('\n');
                var msg = arr[0];
                arr.shift();
                var serverMsg = arr.join('\n');

                LogManager.error(msg);
                return true;
            }
        default:
            {
                if (err.msg) {
                    LogManager.error(err.msg);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
    }
}
```

Problem is regardless I catch the error or not the modal progress bar Ext creates remains displayed, meaning my application is locked for good.

Question is: How do I make Ext fire the form's failure callback and close the progress bar in a pleasant way?

Answer (score 1):

I think the cleanest approach, would be for you to make use of the form submit failure callback to handle the internal server(500) errors.

See docs for more info http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-submit.

You can set a waitMsg attribute and you'll see that Ext will automatically cancel the message being displayed. Like so...

```
myFormPanel.getForm().submit({
    clientValidation: true,
    waitMsg: 'Uploading image...',
    url: 'updateConsignment.php',
    params: {
        newStatus: 'delivered'
    },
    success: function(form, action) {
       Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
    },
    failure: function(form, action) {
        switch (action.failureType) {
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
            case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID: //For your 500
               Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a dirty solution to this problem which is to handle the error using Ext.Error.handle, use Ext.Msg to show the error message abd return false. This is tricky.

By handling the error I can inspect the error event and retrieve some error information.
Showing the error message is the trickier part because the upload's progress bar uses the same infrastructure behind Ext.Msg and Ext.Msg has a bug that it does not allow the programmer to call it like a queue, showing one message then the next when the user clicks OK. It always erases the previous one and displays the new one. **THIS BEHAVIOR CAN LEAD TO TERRIBLE BUGS IF THE USER HAS TO DECIDE OVER TWO PATHS AND THE QUESTION MESSAGE BOX WILL SIMPLE DISAPPEAR!**
Finally, we return false and the error is printed in the console. If we return true at this point the calling function will continue executing and cause problems because the expected information will most likely not be there.

This solution is tricky, dirty and isn't pleasant at all. It works for me right now but I know I'll regret it anytime soon :P

Comment: Just make a ExtJS class with a static method and reuse it in the `form.submit({})` calls. For store sync errors it may be better to listen the proxy for errors.